# No suitable constructor found for Rectangle()

Tags: java

I'm an old VBA fan and have just started learning Java. Everything was going fine until I reached `Point` and `Rectangle`. My code is as follows:

```
// Point demo

import java.awt.Point;  
import java.awt.Rectangle; 

class PointDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point originOne = new Point(25,50);
        Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200); //        Line 9
        System.out.println("OriginOne X = " + originOne.getLocation());
    }
}
```

If I omit Line 9, there is no error. However, once Line 9 is inserted and I recompile, I get the following error:

> ...error: No suitable constructor found for Rectangle(Point, int, int)
>   Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200); // Line 9.....

With a caret under new followed by a slew of other error descriptions for the same line.

But if I substitute the actual values 25, 50  for originOne (line 9), it's OK.

Other info:

All my sources and class files are in the directory  `C:\Java\`. 
All other files and sub-folders(`jdk1.7.0_13`, `JRE7`) are in `C:\Program Files\Java`.

Answer (score 2):

`Rectangle` represents a two dimensional box, it requires 4 parameters, `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`

There are short hand constructors available, that take 1 to 2 parameters, but the basic requirement is for the 4 parameters mentioned above.

Take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for more information

You could use `new Rectangle(originOne, new Dimension(100, 200))` instead...

Answer (score 2):

If you look [At the java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)

You will see that there is no constructor for rectangle that takes in a Point and 2 integers.

There is a constructor that takes in 4 integers though, and there is also one that takes in one point and one dimention.

so you can have a choice of doing:

```
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(originOne.X, originOne.Y, 100, 200);
```

or

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
Dimension myDimension = new Dimension(100,200);
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(originOne, myDimension);
```

depending on which one suits your purposes more.

Comment: Nit pick, but it would be nice to maintain and demonstrate proper coding conventions, as outlined in [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), AKA, how to make friends and influence people ;)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that?

Comment: `r1` and `d1` and not recommended conventions for variables within the Java coding convetions, `r1` and `d1` are more correct (I know, copy and past from the OP, but we need to hold ourselves to as high a standard as possible ;))

Answer (score 1):

`Rectangle` can't take 3 arguments. You could change your code to something like this:

```
import java.awt.Point;  
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Dimension;

class PointDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point originOne = new Point(25,50);
        Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(originOne, new Dimension(100, 200)); // No error
        System.out.println("OriginOne X = " + originOne.getLocation());
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the fact that `Rectangle` has 7 constructors, it might be better to say *"Change your code to something like this"* instead, to highlight the multiple possible choices available to the OP ;) - I know, it's a nit pick

Answer (score 1):

The `Rectangle` class has many constructors but not one with a point and width and height.

```
Point originOne = new Point(25,50);
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(100, 200); //        Line 9
r1.setLocation(originOne);
```

... is one way to do it.

Consult the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for the class to see all the ways to make one that are allowed.

(Note: I have lower cased your variables as that is the java convention.)

Comment: +1 for proper coding conventions and highlighting multiple choices

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the Javadocs for the Rectangle class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html). You will see that there is no constructor which takes a `Point` and two `ints`. You will need to find a different constructor to use which will fit your needs.